# PHP - Eliminar multi files

Tags: php

Eu criei uma maneira de eliminar múltiplos arquivos de uma pasta via *MySQL*.

**Variáveis do *MySQL*:**

```
   $location_files = $listed['ads_image_1'];                    
   $location_files2 = $listed['ads_image_2'];                    
   $location_files3 = $listed['ads_image_3'];
```

***Array* onde vai polos:**

```
   $remove_files = array($location_files, $location_files2, $location_files3);
```

**Função onde vai elimina-los:**

```
   if(file_exists($remove_files)) {

                      $files = glob($remove_files); // get all file names
                         foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
                           if(is_file($file))
                              unlink($file); // delete file
                      }   
               }
```

Mas aconteceu um erro. Alguém poderia ajudar?

**Erro:**

> ```
>   Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.7.9\myads.php on line 819 (if(file_exists)...
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanto a função `file_exists` quanto a função `glob`, **devem** receber uma *string*. Como você está passando um *array*, o erro está sendo mostrado.

Uma alternativa é utilizar um `foreach`, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$remove_files = array($location_files, $location_files2, $location_files3);

foreach($remove_files as $location) {

    if(file_exists($location)) {
        $files = glob($location); // get all file names

        foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
            if(is_file($file))
                unlink($file); // delete file
        }   
    }   
}
```

Ou você poderá utilizar uma função de *callback* com a *array_map*, por exemplo:

```
<?php

function removeFiles($location) {
    if(file_exists($location)) {
        $files = glob($location); // get all file names

        foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
            if(is_file($file))
                unlink($file); // delete file
        }   
    }  
}

$remove_files = array($location_files, $location_files2, $location_files3);

array_map('removeFiles', $remove_files);
```

Comment: Muito agradecido! Era isto mesmo que estava-me a falhar! Já ponho Boa Resposta.. de-me 1min